# Возвращение else

Tags: c#

Есть код, который проверяет время. И он все время возвращает else, даже если значение одинаковые. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```
List<DateTime> time = new List<DateTime>();
public void check_time()
{
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            if (time[0] == DateTime.Now)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Pick!");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("no");
                Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
                Console.WriteLine(time[0]);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: что, прямо миллисекунды совпадают?

Comment: ну а в DateTime.Now идут, вот тут, видимо, и разница.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.

Comment: @tym32167 - Вы снова всех спасли!

Comment: @S.H. что тут скажешь ¯\_(ツ)_/¯